# find Command along with grep and mv

Tags: grep, find, rename, mv

I have many files in a SRC folder. I would like to move all the files that follow a particular pattern from this SRC folder to another DST folder along with rename the file with a required extension.

***Sample Parameters***

SRC directory `/Vinodh`

Files in `/Vinodh` folder are `TEST01`, `TEST02`, `TEST03`, `TEST04`

`TEST02` & `TEST03` contain the word `WORLD`

DST directory `/TEST`

I want to move the `TEST02` & `TEST03` files to `/TEST` folder as `TEST02.txt` and `TEST03.txt`

I will be typing the command as

```
cd /Vinodh
grep -l 'WORLD' *TEST*
mv TEST02 /TEST
mv TEST03 /TEST
cd /TEST
mv TEST02 TEST02.txt
mv TEST03 TEST03.txt
```

I'd like to combine all this to a single line statement or have batch file that copies all the files in a single shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep command to find files containing text string and move them](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/56903)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -D skip -d skip -lZ WORD /Vinodh/*TEST* | xargs -r0 mv -vt /TEST
```

Note that if some of those files are symlinks, moving them could break links.

GNU `grep` can skip devices/fifos with `-D skip`, and directories with `-d skip`, but there's no option to skip symlinks. You'd need a shell where globs can specify file types like `zsh`:

```
grep -lZ WORD /Vinodh/*TEST*(.) | xargs -r0 mv -vt /TEST
```

Would only look in *regular* files.

An alternative is to use `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find /Vinodh/. ! -name . -prune \
  ! -name '.*' -type f -name '*TEST*' -exec grep -lZ WORD {} + |
  xargs -r0 mv -t /TEST
```

And the POSIX variant if you don't have GNU tools:

```
LC_ALL=C find /Vinodh/. ! -name . -prune \
  ! -name '.*' -type f -name '*TEST*' -exec grep -q {} \; \
  -exec mv {} /TEST/ \;
```

Comment: Neither of your examples rename file from `TEST0X` to `TEST0X.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files with `for f...`, then wrap the `mv` inside a conditional (see e.g. [TestsAndConditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) on BashGuide):

```
cd /Vinodh
for f in *TEST* ; do
    if grep -q WORLD "$f" ; then
        mv "$f" "/TEST/$f.txt"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is Bash:

```bsh
source_directory='/Vinodh'
destination_directory='/TEST'
for file in "$source_directory/"*; do
  renamed_file="$(basename "$file")"
  if grep -q 'WORLD' "$file"; then
    echo "Moving \"$file\" to \"$destination_directory/${renamed_file%.*}.txt\""
    mv "$file" "$destination_directory/${renamed_file%.*}.txt"
  fi
done
```

1. Iterate over all files in `$source_directory`.
2. Extract the file name (the part after the last `/`).
3. Look for the string `WORLD` in the file; `grep -q` is **q**uiet, that is, it just sets the exit code and does not print what it did.
4. If the string is found in the file, then move it to `$destination_directory` replacing any suffix with `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one liner for you:

```
cd /Vinodh && for x in $(grep -sl 'WORLD' *TEST*); do mv "$x" "/TEST/$x.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -li "world" /Vinodh/* | awk '{print "mv" " " $1 " " "/TEST/"}' | sh
```